# Express.js route url pattern with parameter and ignore regex

Tags: regex, node.js

In my app I have routes like these:

```
router.get('/blog', function(req, res, next){

   function response(err, data){
     if (err) {
       next(err);
     } else {
       res.render('blog/index', {articles: data});
     }
   };

   // only admin can see draft articles
   if (_adminLoggedIn(req)) {
     Blog.all(response);
   } else {
     Blog.allNonDraft(response);
   }

});
...

router.get('/:slug', function(req, res, next){
...
```

The problem is: when `/blog` url is hit `/:slug` also hit b/c pattern matches.
Even if I put `res.end()` in the end of `/blog` handler it's still hit `/:slug` b/c I am using multi clusters(`/:slug` got hit by different worker)

Is there is a way to define in `/:slug` url to ignore `/blog` route?

Answer (score 0):

Do you call next() inside `router.get('/blog',`? If yes, that's the reason for this behaviour.

You should not call `next();` if not it will look for another route to go into

Comment: No, I am calling ```next()``` in ```/blog``` if there are some errors, but it's not the case. I will add full code of handler to my question

Comment: are you sure that your method does not fail?  `Blog.allNonDraft` if in response you console log the `err` var you get undefined?

Comment: I am sure b/c ```res.render('blog/index', {articles: data});``` page is displayed but in console I see that ```/:slug``` fails

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I did found the problem was that ```/favicon.ico``` was not exist and slug handler was everytime hit when request didn't match some handler before.